# Object not being destroyed until end of the script if it registers spl_autoload_register();

Tags: php, class, object, destructor, autoloader

Object not being destroyed before script ends can someone explain why using `spl_autoload_register()` prevents object from destruction when `unset()`.

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

Does `spl_autoload_register()` have reference to the object that registered it or what happens?

```
class MyAutoLoader {

    public function registerAutoLoader() {

        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

        });

    }

    public function __destruct() {
        echo 'Destroying: ' . get_class($this) . "<br/>";
    }

}

$MyAutoLoader = new MyAutoLoader();

$MyAutoLoader->registerAutoLoader();

unset($MyAutoLoader);

echo 'End of script<br/>';

//End of script
//Destroying: MyAutoLoader
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does spl_autoload_register() have reference to the object that registered it or what happens?

Yes, it does. But, doesn't because `spl_autoload_register` was called inside the class. That's happening because of your `Closure`.

As you can [read](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-162) in manual:

> As of PHP 5.4.0, when declared in the context of a class, the current class is automatically bound to it, making $this available inside of the function's scope. If this automatic binding of the current class is not wanted, then static anonymous functions may be used instead.

When the `closure` has been created inside the class, it'll bound automatically the pseudo-variable `$this`. Then your instance will have two references:

- `$MyAutoLoader` variable;
- `Closure` passed to `spl_autoload_register`.

I've rewritten your example with a few differences which you can see the behavior:

```
class MyAutoLoader {

    private $instance = "Outside";

    public function registerAutoLoader(Closure $closure = null) {

        //If a closure ins't passed as parameter, a new one will be created
        if (!$closure instanceof Closure)
        {
            $this->instance = "Inside";
            //A closure created inside a class will bound the pseudo-variable $this
            $closure = function ($class) {};
        }

        spl_autoload_register($closure);

    }

    public function __destruct() {
        printf('Destroying: %s - %s instance<br/>' , get_class($this) , $this->instance);
    }

}

$MyAutoLoader = new MyAutoLoader();
$MyAutoLoader->registerAutoLoader();

$MyAutoLoader2 = new MyAutoLoader();

//A closure created outside of a class doesn't have the class scope
$MyAutoLoader2->registerAutoLoader(function($class){});

unset($MyAutoLoader , $MyAutoLoader2);

echo 'End of script<br/>';
```

And the result will be:

```
Destroying: MyAutoLoader - Outside the instance
End of script
Destroying: MyAutoLoader - Inside the instance
```

In the last example, the `Closure` has been created out of the class scope. So only the variable `$MyAutoLoader2` has the instance of the class.

Another possible example can be:

```
class MyAutoLoader {

    public function registerAutoLoader(Closure $closure) {

        //Binding the class scope to the closure
        $closure = $closure->bindTo($this);

        spl_autoload_register($closure);

    }

    public function __destruct() {
        printf('Destroying: %s <br/>' , get_class($this));
    }

}

$MyAutoLoader = new MyAutoLoader();
$MyAutoLoader->registerAutoLoader(function($class){});
unset($MyAutoLoader);

echo 'End of script<br/>';
```

In this last example, I'm creating the `Closure` outside of class, but I'm binding the class scope into the class, creating a new reference to `MyAutoLoader` class. The result will be:

```
End of script
Destroying: MyAutoLoader
```

A few more tips from `bind` and `bindTo` you can read at the link below:

[How can I invoke a ReflectionFunction wrapping a closure that utilizes $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772386/how-can-i-invoke-a-reflectionfunction-wrapping-a-closure-that-utilizes-this/40772588#40772588)