# How can I invoke a ReflectionFunction wrapping a closure that utilizes $this?

Tags: php, reflection

This is easiest to explain with an example:

```
class Example {
    private $x;
    public $f;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->x = 10;
        $this->f = function() {
            return $this->x;
        };
    }
}

$ex = new Example();
$f = new ReflectionFunction($ex->f);
echo $f->invoke().PHP_EOL;
```

Running this results in an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

That's because I've used `$this` in the closure, so it's really more like a `ReflectionMethod`, but `ReflectionMethod` doesn't seem to want to take a `closure` as an argument, so I'm not really sure what I can do.

How can I invoke `$ex->f` using reflection?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I really don't know why that behavior is happening. But there's a workaround (well, I found it after a few tests).

As `PHP` doesn't let you explicit the bind of `$this` ([it's bound automatically](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-162)), you have to use an alternative variable:

```
$t = $this;

$this->f = function() use ($t) {
    return $t->x;
};
```

The entire code:

```
class Example {
    private $x;
    public $f;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->x = 10;

        $t = $this;

        $this->f = function() use ($t) {
            return $t->x;
        };
    }
}

$ex = new Example();
$f = new ReflectionFunction($ex->f);
echo $f->invoke().PHP_EOL;
```

And the result wanted

```
10
```

Tested on `PHP 5.4`, `5.5`, `5.6` and `7`.

**UPDATE**

After @mpen answer, I've realized about his restrictions and the use of Reflection.

When you use a [`ReflectionFunction`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) to invoke a `function`, which is a `closure` at least, you should treat that as a `closure`. [`ReflectionFunction`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) has a method called [`ReflectionFunction::getClosure()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunction.getclosure.php).

The Class remains as @mpen created and the use will be as:

```
$ex = new Example();
$f = new ReflectionFunction($ex->f);
$closure = $f->getClosure();
echo $closure().PHP_EOL;
```

But only works on `PHP 7`.

For `PHP 5.4`, `5.5` and `5.6` you'll have to bind the class and scope. Weird, but it's the only way that I found using [Closure::bindTo()](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) or [Closure::bind()](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php):

```
$ex = new Example();
$f = new ReflectionFunction($ex->f);    
$closure = $f->getClosure();
$class = $f->getClosureThis();
$closure = $closure->bindTo($class , $class);
echo $closure().PHP_EOL;
```

Or just:

```
$ex = new Example();
$f = new ReflectionFunction($ex->f);    
$class = $f->getClosureThis();
$closure = Closure::bind($f->getClosure() , $class , $class);
echo $closure().PHP_EOL;
```

It's very important to pass the class as scope (second parameter) which will determine whether you can access `private`/`protected` variable or not.

The second paramater also could be the class name as:

```
$closure = $closure->bindTo($class , 'Example');//PHP >= 5.4
$closure = $closure->bindTo($class , get_class($class));//PHP >= 5.4
$closure = $closure->bindTo($class , Example::class);//PHP 5.5
```

But I didn't concerned about performance, so the class passed twice is just fine to me.

There's also the method [Closure::call()](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php) which can be used to change the scope, but also just for `PHP >= 7`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really a solution for me. I need to be able to call arbitrary closures.

Comment: @mpen I've updated the question which all the things I've tested