# PHP - Encapsulation when referenced in function scope

Tags: php

I was going through the [PHP 7.0 changes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) and came across [Closure Call](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.closure-call-method). 
The code in the documentation is the following.

```
<?php
class A {private $x = 1;}

// Pre PHP 7 code
$getXCB = function() {return $this->x;}; // this line
$getX = $getXCB->bindTo(new A, 'A'); // intermediate closure
echo $getX();
```

My question is how is the line after the first comment able to return the x value? Does this not break encapsulation?

It seems like when x is referenced inside the function closure we are actually in class scope for some reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772386/how-can-i-invoke-a-reflectionfunction-wrapping-a-closure-that-utilizes-this/40772588#40772588 It can give to you a few tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the new function that is created with `bindTo` sets the scope of that new function to `A`. This is as described in the [documentation on `bindTo`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php):

> Create and return a new anonymous function with the same body and bound variables as this one, but possibly with a different bound object and a new class scope.
>
> The “bound object” determines the value $this will have in the function body and the “class scope” represents a class which determines which private and protected members the anonymous function will be able to access. Namely, the members that will be visible are the same as if the anonymous function were a method of the class given as value of the *newscope* parameter.

Note the last phrase *"...as if..."*.