# Equivalent of Function.prototype.apply in PHP?

Tags: php, function, this

In Javascript, you can control what object the `this` keyword referes to by using `apply`. In the following example, `foo` will be called with `this` equal to `bar`:

```
function foo() { console.log(this); }

let bar = {};
foo.apply(bar);
```

Is there any way to achieve the same effect in PHP? Just creating a function referencing `$this` outside of a class seems possible, but it is (unsurprisingly) just treated like any undefined variable.

I am aware of [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), but it does not let me assign to `$this`. I am thinking reflection might be useful here, but I am not sure how.

Comment: `$this` refers to the instance for mostly all OOP languages (some use `self` but same idea). You don't want to modify the reference to the instance. Javascript doesn't have a clear difference between functions and instances, also, it is not an OOP language, but a prototype oriented language. You can not reproduce such things in PHP because it would have no sense at all. What you can do is to store another variable, even pass it by reference if you need to, such as : `function foo(&$newThis = null) { var_dump($newThis ?? $this); }`

Comment: in PHP 'this' refers to the current object instance and not the current scope as in JS. What exactly you are trying to achievei?

Comment: I think the most near that you can get is the [Closure::call](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php) and/or the two steps [Closure::bindTo](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php). 'Cause you can bind an object to be `$this` and call the function. But its only for functions inside an object.

Comment: @EriksKlotins To be honest, I am not trying to achieve anything in particular. Just poking around at the language, trying to understand how it works in relation to other languages. I am well aware that what I am suggesting here may be impossible, undesirable, or both.

Comment: Have you try to use [Closure::fromCallable](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php) with `->bindTo()` method?

Comment: @GabrielHeming `bindTo` seems to do the trick! Feel free to post as an answer, or I will self answer. Thank you!

Comment: @acelot Just did: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a164b07ca3ac391f29b6a584421af8c03ff58619 Works great! As I said above, feel free to post as an answer, or I will self answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you could read in the comments, in PHP `$this` refers to an object context and that could differs from JavaScript context.

However, talking about scope, you can work with closures that carriers an object scope. That scope, which is inside $this variable, can be changed using [`Closure::bindTo`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) or [`Closure::bind`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php).

Both of them have the intention to change the closure scope. It means to change the object inside `$this` variable.

Here a simple example:

```
class Foo
{
    private $number;

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    public function getClosure()
    {
        return function() {
            echo $this->number;
        };
    }        
}
```

And its use:

```
$foo = new Foo(10);
$closure = $foo->getClosure();
$closure();
```

Output:

> 10

The number 10 is the value from `$number` private variable inside `Foo` class from `$foo` instance.

Changing the scope, we can obtain a different result while we access the same variable from other instance:

```
$foo = new Foo(10);
$foo2 = new Foo(50);
$closureFoo = $foo->getClosure();
$closureFoo();//First execution

echo ' and ';

$closureFoo2 = $closureFoo->bindTo($foo2);
$closureFoo2();//Second execution
```

Output:

> 10 and 50

If you want to use [`Closure::bind`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php), that's the code:

```
$closureFoo2 = Closure::bind($closureFoo , $foo2);
```

you can find more examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40772588/1628790

Answer (score 1):

Using the insights from other answers and comments, I came up with this implementation of `apply` in PHP:

```
function apply($func, $new_this, ...$args) {
    Closure::fromCallable($func)->bindTo($new_this)(...$args);
}
```

Not sure if this is useful in any way. However, it can be done. Note that this only works if `$new_this` is an object, and not e.g. a string or number.