# Does unsetting a PHP object containing a PDO object close the PDO connection?

Tags: php, pdo

Consider the following PHP snippet:

```
$dbw = new db_writer($table_name);       // establishes a PDO connection
$success = $dbw->insert_record($record);
unset($dbw);
```

Does unsetting the $dbw object result in the PDO connection closing?

The whole point of my db_writer class is to preserve the connection so that, if desired, the class can perform multiple operations without having to make/break the connection for each operation. Thus the class does not ever unset the PDO object, which I presume *does* close the connection.

Comment: Just curious, why do you ask?

Comment: I can say, with 99.9%, if the object is the only thing which has a PDO reference, the connection will closed as soon as possible.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The sites I build live in economy shared hosting plans that usually have centralized database servers. I need to be careful about dangling connections.

Comment: @GabrielHeming There may be multiple object instances, each with their own PDO connection. A given object will only have one.

Comment: what do you mean, "dangling"? in what circumstance it would dangle?

Comment: If there's any reference, the object will not be destroyed. Take a look in the link below, it's about `closure` keeping a reference of a object and delaying his end: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348781/object-not-being-destroyed-until-end-of-the-script-if-it-registers-spl-autoload/41462603#41462603

Comment: @YourCommonSense By "dangling" I mean a database connection that has not been closed. As for what circumstance, that's what I'm trying to understand. Perhaps the first question I should have asked is "If I destroy a PDO object, is the database connection closed?"

Comment: Still it's unclear what circumstance you are aiming at. In other words, is there any *particular* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've substituted my database classes for my old techniques. All is working as expected, no problem. But my old code was explicitly closing every database connection (i.e., mysqli_close). I don't have an explicit close of the PDO object,. Perhaps I need a __destruct method for the wrapper class that does set the PDO references to NULL.

Answer (score 2):

According to `PDO` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) when you set `PDO` object value to `null` it closes the connection. Hovewer there can be situations when some object keeps reference to `PDO` object instance. In this case connection will be closed only at the end of `PHP` script execution.

Also there is `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` options that allows you to create persistent `PDO` connection that will not be closed on script execution end and can be reused on the next script run.

Comment: I suppose I could add a "close" method that would destroy the PDO object. That would be its only purpose. If I can avoid that by just unsetting my object, it makes my code simpler. I don't need or want to persist the connection beyond the life of its containing object.